# Неправильная генерация числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть некий код

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    a=random.randint(1,99999999)
    str(a).rjust(8,"0")
    print(a)
    print(len(str(a)))
```

при генерации числа есть возможность словить число с len == 7, как это можно исправить, что бы генерировались только восьмизначные числа

Comment: random.randint(10000000,99999999)

Comment: нет нужно именно от единицы

Comment: чтобы потом с помощью rjust добавить нулей вперёд

Comment: a = str(a).rjust(8,"0")

Comment: Работает, создавай ответ я галочку поставлю

Comment: неправильный заголовок вопроса...